# Unable to get the Internet Explorer proxy settings using WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()

Tags: c#, windows, http, proxy

I'm using "WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()" method to get the proxy settings configured in the Internet Explorer. It works successfully in most of the systems. In some system the same method was not detecting the proxy settings available in the system.

My code is,

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
IWebProxy iproxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
iproxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.Proxy = iproxy;
```

Note:

My application will use the highest .Net framework installed in the system. This issue arises in Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 10

Comment: Write a new console application with only these lines...and run it on that system...are you able to recreate the problem? Is the app running with elevated privileges?

Comment: run netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie on those machines

Comment: @kennyzx I have already tried, but got the same result. The application will run in the user account and I want to use the proxy of that particular user only.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie Command return no proxy even if the proxy is configured in ie

Comment: it does for me. are you running the command as administrator?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Yes, I'm running the command as administrator only. Even though it was showing "no proxy <Direct access>". In the same system windows update also get failed. When I checked the windows update log, it shows "Proxy server = null".

Comment: its an IT issue if Windows update fails. you need working winhttp proxy settings and client does not have one. of course you can write your own IWebProxy other than the system default and give it a UI in settings but from a usability point if client is not willing to fix the winhttp proxy for windows update what's the chance to get the client to enter a new proxy on your settings UI?